# My screen keeps going black, and I cannot resurrect it

Tags: xubuntu, xorg

I'm running Xubuntu 20.04.2 on several machines, and I have screen blanking disabled on them all, but one of them keeps going blank on me at odd moments, and I cannot get it back alive with the usual key presses. I'd like ideas about the cause...

It's not hardware because CTL-ALT-F1 brings up a console screen as usual, but C-A-F7 just goes back to blank.  I can SSH in from another machine and all seems well; I can even do it with X forwarding.  If I use either of those to "shutdown -r now" the screen shows a brief Xubutnu logo and twirlie before the reboot.

It seems to happen when I do something on that station that will take a while.   Usually a large dd command or some such.

Any ideas?  Maybe just a way to restart the X server.  I'd rather do that than a reboot.

Comment: Check the logs, it could be graphics card related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using lightdm, you can use the following command to restart your display manager:

```
sudo systemctl restart lightdm
```

Use <kbd>CTL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> if it doesn't take you to your graphical session automatically.

To help diagnose the issue, check out the `dmesg -T` and `journalctl` commands for errors.

Comment: Thanks.  The restart works.  And I have a way to proceed with diagnosis.